# How to check a url or webpage exists in ajax or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

While creating a profile, the user can fill up his websites/blog-links/,that shown his profile page.
Before to save this link into the database I wanted to check that the given url/webpage exists or not.

Is there any way to do this via javascript/ajax/?
like on load of user profile page, it will check the url.

```
      if url/webpage exists 
         then url links will shown to user profile page.
```

Comment: I have not done this kind of thing.But I think by checking the website from `whois api` can help you to know whether the site is available or not.

Answer (score 2):

You cant guarantee that users websites support cross-domain requests so create a proxy on your server and send  the header of the site. If status is 200 then load the website in IFrame

Answer (score 1):

You could use [OpenURI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html) from Ruby to open the URL and check the HTTP status code. Anything between 200 and 300 would mean success. [Here's a list of all HTTP status codes and their description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [Net::HTTP library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/index.html).

```
require "net/http"
url = URI.parse("http://www.google.com/")
req = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
res = req.request_head(url.path)
```

At this point res is a [Net::HTTPResponse object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPResponse.html) containing the result of the request.